# rerun full code with new status in python

Tags: python, time, raspberry-pi

i'm working on automation system and i'm handling lights with mobile app. now i want that my Raspberry Pi keep fetching status from database after 3-4 seconds and it keep rerunning code.
i have written a code and my code is rerunning  but with the same values it keep running. like if i change status of light to OFF my code start running and it will give output also 0 but in the middle of this running code i change my light status to ON it still keeps on running with old status. i want that my code rerun and update values while running.

**Code**

```
import pymysql
import Rpi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
a=[]
a2=[]
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(20,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(21,GPIO.OUT)

def do_something(sc):
    db=pymysql.connect('mysql.freehostia.com','usalat9_123','balebalebale1.x','usalat9_123')
    cursor=db.cursor()
    sql="SELECT * FROM new_light_table"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    results=cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results:
         a.append(row[2])
    r1=a[0]
    r2=a[1]
    r3=a[2]
    r4=a[3]
    if r1 == 1:
       GPIO.output(12,0)
    if r1 == 0:
       GPIO.output(12,1)
    if r2 == 1:
       GPIO.output(16,0)
    if r2 == 0:
       GPIO.output(16,1)
    if r3 == 1:
       GPIO.output(20,0)
    if r3 == 0:
       GPIO.output(20,1)
    if r4 == 1:
       GPIO.output(21,0)
    if r4 == 0:
       GPIO.output(21,1)
    print(r1)
    print(r2)
    print(r3)
    print(r4)
    db.commit()
    db.close()
#time.sleep(4)

s.enter(60, 1, do_something, (s,))
s.run()
```

Comment: Could you check the light status more frequently, like once every 100 ms? And update if the light status has changed?